# nodejs sends email from non existing email

Tags: node.js, email, nodemailer

I want to use an non-existing email(e.g. no-reply@anyhost.com) to send email to welcome our users.

Here is an example how to do it by Ruby on Rails([ActionMailer](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html))

```
# app/mailers/application_mailer.rb
class ApplicationMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: "from@example.com"
end
```

Is there a way to do it in nodejs? The library [nodemailer](https://github.com/nodemailer/nodemailer) needs to use existing email address:

```
var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport('smtps://user%40gmail.com:pass@smtp.gmail.com');
```

Is it possible to use an non-existing email?

Comment: You misunderstand what that line of JavaScript does. It doesn't tell nodemailer what email address to use, it tells nodemailer what SMTP server to use and what username and password for authentication. Whether you're using Rails or Node.js, to send emails you need an SMTP server. In Rails [you have to supply the same kind of configuration](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html#action-mailer-configuration-for-gmail).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On my Ubuntu server with node.js I use sendmail

First I install sendmail

```
 apt-get sendmail
```

Then I install nodemailer

```
 npm install nodemailer
```

Then I include it in my file

```
 nodemailer = require('nodemailer'),
 transporter = nodemailer.createTransport(),
```

Finally I send my mail

```
 transporter.sendMail({
          from: 'admin@mydomain.com',
          to: results.email,
          subject: 'Password Reset',
          text: 'Your new password is: ' + password
        });
```

Please note that sendmail is not as reliable as actually sending an email from a real email address and it is more likely to get marked a spam. However, it is a free and easy to implement option useful in development, or if you don't mind reminding users to check their spam.

Comment: After looking into action mail of ruby on rails , I found it also depends on sendmail program which doesn't need  smtp client

Comment: @StevenDStanton your above code giving me following error:```this.transporter.mailer = this;
                                ^

TypeError: Cannot set property 'mailer' of undefined ``` did you not faced the same error and what is the solution? what are the options you provided in **createTransport( )** method?

Comment: @KPal Sorry for the delay, I just saw your comment. This is because the latest update to the nodemailer plugin broke backwards compatibility. I will try to get an update to my answer out soon

Comment: Does this work even now? This does not seem to work for me now. Can someone confirm in the latest version

Answer (score 1):

Nodemailer requires an smtp sever to send its email rather then a `signed by` email.

Depending on your volume of mail I would use [Sendgrid](http://sendgrid.com) as they have a **free** tier offering **12,000 emails** **a month** and an amazing [node package](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-nodejs). With them so long you own the domain they let you send an email as anyone. I used nodemailer for a long time but, depending on how you use it you may find you drops some emails with too many firing off at the same time.

Sendgrid isn't the only mail provide theirs also mailgun, but I've always had the best success with Sendgrid

Comment: Nodemailer doesn't require "an actual email client," it requires an SMTP server.

Comment: Very true, I was simply trying to simplify

Comment: Yes, nodemailer with sendgrid is highly recomended.